# matplotlib subplots do not show the exact x tick labels passed to it as list

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a plot of `Accuracy` versus the `var_smoothing` curve of 4 different instances. My values are:

```
var_smoothing_values
>>
[1e-09, 1e-06, 0.001, 1]

gauss_accuracies
>>
[0.728, 0.8, 0.826, 0.832]
```

I have used the 2 subplots and on the second subplot, I am plotting this as:

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))

ax[1].plot(var_smoothing_values,gauss_accuracies,marker='*',markersize=12)
ax[1].set_ylabel('Accuracy')
ax[1].set_xlabel('var_smoothing values')
ax[1].set_title('Accuracy vs var_smoothing | GaussianNB',size='large')

plt.show()
```

`ax[1].set_xticks(var_smoothing_values)` shows only 3 ticks.

How can I show only 4 ticks which corresponds to each of  my `var_smoothing_values`??

Comment: As your ticks are quite close together, you might want to use a logscale: `ax[1].set_xscale('log')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the log scale on the x-axis since your x-values span acoss several orders of magnitude

```
ax[1].set_xscale('log')
ax[1].set_xticks(var_smoothing_values);
```

[image]